# error checking and flashing error messages with FlaskForm

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a form that is setup as below and ultimately, the error I get in debug mode is `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed`.  I understand why, but I would like this error to get presented to the user so they know the issue.

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    company_url = StringField('Company Website', validators=[DataRequired(), URL(message='Must be a valid URL')])
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('pass_confirm',
                                                        message='Passwords must match')]
    )
    pass_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register!')
```

However, when an incorrect URL structure is entered into the form and submitted, I cannot get it to flash an error message in the html page for the user.  The html page is below.  I will place the base.html below as well.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        {{form.company_url.label}}{{form.company_url()}}<br>
        {{form.password.label}}{{form.password()}}<br>
        {{form.pass_confirm.label}}{{form.pass_confirm()}}<br>
        {{form.submit()}}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   ...some code here
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Just an image -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <span class="align-bottom text-light">Creating connections, saving time</span>
</nav>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} {% if messages %} {% for
    message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="close"
        data-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      {{message}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %} {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The views.py is:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = Buyers(
            company_url=form.company_url.data,
            password=form.password.data
        )

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Thank you for registering.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

How do I error handle in forms to make sure the user is aware that they have entered a URL with an incorrect structure?  I am in debug mode and right now, the register.html page just basically reloads without any message as to why.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py :

```
import validators

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        isUrlValid=validators.url(form.company_url.data)
        if isUrlValid==True:
            user = Buyers(
                company_url=form.company_url.data,
                password=form.password.data
            )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Thank you for registering.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash("URL is not valid. Please enter a valid URL")
            return redirect(url_for('register'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that information.  I did try the code you suggested and I am still unable to get it to flash a message.  The strange part is that then I register correctly, the message "Thank you for registering" works fine.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: you can put a simple display to check if condition is called if URL is not valid . And check it in the debug logs.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Just so I understand, how would I write the display?  I haven't done that before.  Thank you.

Comment: else:
            print("url is not valid ") flash("URL is not valid. Please enter a valid URL")
            return redirect(url_for('register'))